# Reading LARGE data file in Java, only displaying a 1/10 of the results

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, large-files

I've tried every method known to man with regards to reading a file, and every time I am only getting a very small portion of the actual data back. 
Currently, I have:

```
 File file = new File("Files/newCA_Features_20190301.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine())
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

This is the simplest of the methods I've tried. But no matter how complex the method, I always get back the same 7,005 lines out of 122,670 lines. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Are you sure the file has 122k lines?  Many editors will 'wrap' the text if they exceed a certain length.

Comment: If you are on a Unix/Linux machine, what does running `wc -l Files/newCA_Features_20190301.txt` on the command line tell you?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I ran the equivalent in Terminal (Windows) and it gave me the numbers mentioned in the post.

Comment: *"the same 7,005 lines"* Would that be the **last** 7,005 lines, i.e. the other 115,665 lines scrolled out of the command line window, because the command line output buffer overflowed?

Comment: *FYI:* Don't use [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for line-reading a file. `Scanner` is insanely slow. Use [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead.

Comment: @Andreas are you serious?! That's it?